# PHP : Failed to delete multiple selected data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Currently, I created a system that enables the user to delete multiple data by using the checkbox.

The step is like this:

1) user select team, time before and time after at dashboard.php. The user click button 'Search' to display the result. The display result use AJAX. AJAX will redirect to range.php

2) User can select any data row that displays and delete.

My problem is, delete function is failed although I do the correct step and code. Below is the current code:

range.php

```
    <?php

    require_once "../../../config/configPDO.php";
    require_once "../../../config/check.php";

    $email = $_SESSION['login_user'];


    if(isset($_POST["From"], $_POST["to"], $_POST["team"]))
    {

    $result = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid WHERE ot_users.team_id = '".$_POST['team']."' AND report_date BETWEEN '".$_POST["From"]."' AND '".$_POST["to"]."' ORDER BY ot_report.report_date DESC";
    $sql = $conn->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $sql -> execute();

    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        $checkbox = $_POST['check'];
        for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
            $del_id = $checkbox[$i];

            $sql2 = "DELETE FROM ot_report WHERE report_id=:report_id";
            $query2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
            $query2->execute(array(':report_id' => $del_id));

            header("Location: dashboard.php");
        }
    }


    if($sql->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        echo'

        <form method="post" action="">
        <div><a href="../pdf.php?from='.$_POST["From"].'&to='.$_POST["to"].' &team='.$_POST["team"].'" target="_blank"><u>PDF View</u></a></div><br>
        <div class="row" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
        <table class = "table-bordered" width = "100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th width = "10%"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAl"> All</th>
        <th width = "3%">id</th>
        <th width = "15%">Date</th>
        <th width = "25%">Supervisor</th>
        <th width = "30%">Task Name</th>
        <th width = "10%">Status</th>
        <th width = "7%">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
        $i=0;
        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $datereport = $row['report_date'];
            $datereport2 = strtotime($datereport);
            $report_date = date('d M Y', $datereport2);

            $status=$row['report_status'];
            if($status=="Pending")
            {
                $color="color:blue";
            }
            else 
            {
                $color="color:green";
            }

            if ($row['ot_start'] == '00:00:00'){
                $ot_start = '-';
            }else{}

            if ($row['ot_end'] == '00:00:00'){
                $ot_end = '-';
            }else{}


            echo'<tr>';
                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" name="check[]" value='.$row['report_id'].'></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["report_id"].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$report_date.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["fullname"].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["task_name"].'</td>';
                echo '<td align="center" style='.$color.'><strong>'.$status.'</strong></td>';
                echo '<td align="center">';
                echo '<a class="btn-view btn-primary btn-sm" href="view_task/view_task.php?report_id='. $row["report_id"] .'" data-toggle="tooltip">View</a>';
                echo '<a class="btn-view btn-danger btn-sm" href="delete.php?report_id='. $row["report_id"] .'" onClick=\'return confirm("Do you want to remove team?")\'>Delete</a></td>';
                echo '</td>';

            echo '</tr>';
            $i++;

        }
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td><p align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn-danger btn-sm" name="save">DELETE</button></p></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</form>';

    }
    else
    {
        echo '
        <table class = "table-bordered" width = "100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th width = "5%">id</th>
        <th width = "12%">Date</th>
        <th width = "29%">Supervisor</th>
        <th width = "23%">Task Name</th>
        <th width = "7%">From</th>
        <th width = "7%">To</th>
        <th width = "10%">Status</th>
        <th width = "7%">Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="8">No report found</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    echo '</body></table></div></div>';

    }

    ?>

    <script>
    $("#checkAl").click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    </script>
```

Can anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: I’d start by fixing the terribly invalid HTML you are creating there, you have nesting errors all over the place.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql2 = "DELETE FROM ot_report WHERE report_id=:report_id";
```

Try changing this to:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM ot_report WHERE report_id LIKE ?";            
$sql2 = $conn->prepare($query);
$sql2->bind_param("i", $del_id);
$sql2->execute();
```

Comment: OP is using PDO not mysqli